# Unable to start React app via Termux (`Package exports for ... do not define a valid '.' target`)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, termux

I am unable to successfully run `npm start` on an application I've created via `create-react-app` on Termux; I have not done any modifications from the base application beyond running `rm -rf node-module` followed by `npm install` in an unsuccessful bid to get it to work, I also tried `npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0` to no avail. This is the error dump:

```sh
Error: Package exports for '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/…/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss' do not define a valid '.' target
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:455:13)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:388:16)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:487:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:850:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/…/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parse.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:958:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:994:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
…
```

I'm completely new to React, so any solutions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it turns out the solution is to update the packages (presumably at least Node, although simply entering `node install` broke the installation) via `pkg update`; no more error.